# Saturation current in diode

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

I don't quite get why there should be a saturation current in a PN junction diode in reverse bias.

The electrons in the N side should be pulled toward the battery, and the battery allows electrons to flow toward the P side. These electrons should now travel through the electric field of the depletion region back to the N side, and the loop is completed.

Hence, there should be no constant saturation current, since nothing is being opposed.

Comment: How do you propose that an electron, a minority carrier, 'flow' through the p-type region? It will undergo recombination. Note that in forward bias, electrons don't flow through the device - the go into the junction and recombine there with holes coming from the p-type side.

Comment: Oh, that should resolve it